# Mutt, not respecting mailcap search order?

Tags: email, mutt, mime-types

According to the [docs](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-5.html) (see "Search Order"), the mailcap below should behave like this:

- When I read a message, it'll be processed through lynx
- When I browse to the attachment screen, and select the text/html attachment, it'll open in firefox

`text/html;      firefox --new-tab %s
 text/html;      lynx -dump %s; nametemplate=%s.html; copiousoutput`

It's not doing that though-- Either way, I get output of lynx.

Does anyone have an idea about how to fix this?

Comment: I use separate text/html lines for each of firefox and lynx, where lynx takes the copiousoutput flag. Check mutt documentation section 'Search order'.

Comment: I think I screwed up my copy and paste,  those are supposed to be separate lines (and basically match  the "search order"  example,   minus the conditional that checks if X is running,  and with Firefox instead of Netscape. Will fix the post when I'm back at a a computer